# Firefox cannot start up on Archlinux any more

Tags: firefox, arch-linux

It was working fine before. But today the following ways of turning on firefox all failed.

```
$ firefox
$ firefox --start-debugger-server
$ firefox --safe-mode
```

addons.xpi WARN    Expected add-on followonsearch@mozilla.com is missing from the system add-on location.
firefox processes were shown in the following command

```
$ ps aux | grep firefox
```

I did `killall firefox` in between each attempt.

Firefox version is : 54.0.1

Comment: Try reinstalling firefox from package cache pacman -U /path/to/pkg

Comment: I actually did `pacman -S firefox ` firstly, and it did not work. But I also did what you suggested, `pacman -U /var/cache/pkg/<ff.tar.xz>`, then I attempted running from my windows manager, by clicking the FF icon, then nothing showed up, but I can see two FF processes when doing `ps aux | grep firefox`.

Answer (score 0):

I think all add on save into you home directory if you did not customize it. you can remove all ~/.mozilla/firefox. then restart firefox. however, this solution will remove all your history and saved password, ect

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But
I did `rm -rf ~/.mozilla`,  problem remained. 

I am wondering is there any debugging mode of firefox that I can see what is actually happening? Otherwise, is there any debugging tools that I can use to probe the firefox process?

Answer (score 0):

run **pacman -Rs** which should remove every Firefox dependencies and configuration files that were installed when installing Firefox.

Then you can manually delete the configuration files at **~/.mozilla** to remove every other file belonging to Firefox, after which you can reinstall your Firefox using **pacman -S firefox**.

If the above fails, you should run this: **pacman -Rsc firefox**, but...

**Note:** Running this operation is recursive, which means it can remove many potentially needed packages and must be used with care.

You can then run **pacman -Syu** to get the latest available updates, but it might take quite a while depending on how up-to-date the system is. It should synchronize the repository databases and update the system's packages, excluding "local" packages that are not in the configured repositories.

This should work for you.

Comment: I did what you told me, and even I did a reboot after that. But problem remains. Could you help me more, please?

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me as well today, and none of the suggestions fixed the problem.
In my case, I was running ArcoLinux in a VirtualBox VM, and removing the "3D" option in the display of the VM fixed the problem for good.